# I had a passport card as a kid, But lost it. Can I say I never had one when applying for a new one?

Tags: passports, us-citizens, passport-renewals

I'm trying to get a new US passport to go overseas in the winter. I had a passport card once before. I got it when I was 9, a minor. I am nineteen now so this passport is useless. Because I was a minor when it was issued, I don't have to renew it. I want to just apply for a new one.

The passport application asked if I have ever been issued a passport before. If I click yes, they need some info, including my old card number. The card is either somewhere in my mother's house or lost, so I don't have convenient access to the card number.

Another option is to say i was never issued a passport.

Is it wrong for me to say that? If my old passport is expired, do they care?

Comment: I'm assuming you're filling up a DS-11. It would be wrong to say you never had a passport. You will need to report it as lost (DS64) and get a replacement by scheduling an appointment at https://iafdb.travel.state.gov/

Answer (score 23):

If you hover over the little question mark next to the answer box for that question, it says if you don't know the number put "UNKNOWN" in the passport number field and "0000" for the year of expiration, so I guess that's what you do.

Comment: Worst case, you will also have to fill out a DS-64.

Comment: Which also asks for number and issue date. But, you are right.